# No compiler error/warning for not catching/throwing exception

Tags: java, android, sqlexception

I don't understand why the compiler does not warn me about not catching or throwing an `SQLException`. Here's the situation:

I have defined this interface:

```
public interface GenericDatabaseManager {
    public void createTables(DataBase model) throws SQLException;
}
```

Then I created this class that implements the given interface:

```
public class SqliteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements
        GenericDatabaseManager {

    @Override
    public void createTables(DataBase model) throws SQLException {
        // Code that throws SQLException
    }
```

And finally I'm calling this SqliteHelper.createTables() from here:

```
public class DatabaseManager extends CoreModule {
    private boolean createUpdateDB(final String dbString, final String appId) {
        // Previous code...

        if (oldVer == -1) {
            dbCoreModel.addModel(dbModel);
            dbCoreModel.getManager().createTables(dbModel);
            return true;
        }

        // More code...
    }

}
```

`dbCoreModel.getManager()` returns a `GenericDatabaseManager` instance. But the compiler shows no error on `dbCoreModel.getManager().createTables(dbModel);` line, although this line throws an `SQLException`.

Does anyone have an idea about why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: about `SQLException` does not need to be catched because it's a `RuntimeException`. [This is not true](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html). Here's an example:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

interface Interface {
    public void throwsSQLException() throws SQLException;
}

class Test implements Interface {

    @Override
    public void throwsSQLException() throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException();
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface i = new Test();
        i.throwsSQLException();
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```

The compiler DOES show an error in `i.throwsSQLException();` in this case.

Comment: Useless to ask whether "Previous code..." contains a `try {` and "More code..." contains a `} catch (SQLException e) {`, right ? :D

Comment: Then, as PC. answered, you're not using `java.sql.SQLException`, but `android.database.SQLException`. Check your `import`s.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`android.database.SQLException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/SQLException.html) is a runtime exception.

In java it is not necessary to catch or declare throws for runtime exceptions. Read a detailed description about [`RuntimeExceptions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) in java [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html)

Comment: [SQLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) is not a runtime exception.

Comment: `android.database.SQLException` is a `RuntimeException`, [`java.sql.SQLException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) isn't.

Comment: the question is about `android.database.SQLException` and not `java.sql.SQLException`

Comment: The questio or the answer do not specfie what SQLException is about.

Comment: @onof I am using Android JUnit